# WPF How to set DataTemplate for DataGridCell dynamically

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate, datagridcell

I want make DataGrid, it will has 2 columns. First column has such a DataTemplate:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <ComboBox>
                    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">ComboBox Item #1</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem >ComboBox Item #2</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem >ComboBox Item #3</ComboBoxItem> 
               </ComboBox>
           </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Second column must has more then one DataTemplate. First template - default template (does't matter what exactly). That template corresponds to `ComboBox Item #1`.
Now imagine that you pick up second combobox item and DataTemplate of second column changes to DataTemplate, corresponds to `ComboBox Item #2` item. For example, like that:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBox FontSize="14"/> 
</DataTemplate>
```

The same about `ComboBox Item #3`. Pick up and DataTemplate of second column changes to DataTemplate, corresponds to that item. For example:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox>
        <ComboBoxItem >Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem >Item 2</ComboBoxItem> 
    </ComboBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

I know about `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector` and `DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplateSelector` classes. But it doesn't what I want :( Any idea?

Comment: Well, actually `CellTemplateSelector` does exactly what you want.

Comment: As I know, `CellTemplateSelector` allow to specify DataTemplate for cells dinamically dependent on type of data, that we are **binding** to column. So if data type is Int32 I can specify DataTemplateInteger, if data type is String I can specify DataTemplateString and so on. But it is not quite I want. Can you write some code sample?

Comment: Dude, I think you don't understand what I want, your sample is useless for me :( It is just classic usage of `CellTemplateSelector`
sry, I flagged ur post as unconstructive, cause it contains google link at the beginning :)

Comment: Oh, sorry for trying to help. I\`ll see myself out then.